# UIActivityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler not called for whatsapp activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

UIActivityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler not called for whatsapp activity.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Please share solution if any.

```
NSArray *applicationActivities = @[[[JBWhatsAppActivity alloc] init]];

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = nil;
if(installed)
    activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
else
    activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

// Setting subject field while sharing app with email
[activityViewController setValue:@"Check out this Site !" forKey:@"subject"];

NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypePrint,
                                UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypeAirDrop
                                ];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;



[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString * __nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray * __nullable returnedItems, NSError * __nullable activityError)
 {

 }
 ];


[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: can you show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];
if (text) {
    [sharingItems addObject:text]; // text to share
}
if (image) {
    [sharingItems addObject:image]; // UIImage to share
}
if (url) {
    [sharingItems addObject:url]; // url to share
}

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];

if ( [activityController respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ) {
    // iOS8
    activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView =
    sourceView;
    activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0);
}

[activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString * __nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray * __nullable returnedItems, NSError * __nullable activityError)
{
     //Your Code goes here
}];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the answer?

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the answer?